# In AngularJS, can I add a block of HTML that also has angular template data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm adding contents of an html file on my page. To act as a "preview" that needs to change as the user adds content. For the sake of argument,

```
<div>
    {{introText}}
</div>
```

I'm using `$http.get()` to grab the content and `$sce.trustAsHtml()` to insert the html on the page. The issue is `{{introText}}` isn't bound to the controller so it's not recognized.

I haven an input with `ng-model="introText"` and I'd like to update `{{introText}}`.

Note: my html file is much longer but the html provided is just an example.

Comment: Can you post the relevant controller code?

Comment: depending on details you need $compile or $interpolate

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `$interpolate`:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$interpolate', function($scope, $interpolate) {
    $scope.introText = 'some text';
    var templates = ['<div>{{introText}}</div>', '<h1>{{introText}}</h1>']    
    var i = 0;
    $scope.inter = $interpolate(templates[i]);
    $scope.template = function(){      
      i = 1 - i;
      $scope.inter = $interpolate(templates[i]);
    };
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <input type='text' ng-model='introText'/>    
    <input type='button' value='Change template' ng-click='template()'>    
    <p ng-bind-html="inter({introText})"></p>    
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could the fact that my input with `ng-model` is added dynamically cause an issue? It may explain why this approach isn't working for me.